# How to get user's password expiration date from Active Directory?

Tags: c#, asp.net, asp.net-mvc, active-directory

I have implemented implemented Active Directory authentication in ASP.NET MVC 5 using LDAP. I want to know how to get a user's

1. Account Locked (boolean)
2. Password Expired (boolean)
3. Password Expiry Date (DateTime)

This is my current code:

```
using System.Web.Mvc;
using System.Web.Security;
using MvcApplication.Models;

[HttpPost]
public ActionResult Login(LoginModel model, string returnUrl)
{
    if (!this.ModelState.IsValid)
    {
        return this.View(model);
    }

    if (Membership.ValidateUser(model.UserName, model.Password))
    {
        FormsAuthentication.SetAuthCookie(model.UserName, model.RememberMe);

        if (this.Url.IsLocalUrl(returnUrl) && returnUrl.Length > 1 && returnUrl.StartsWith("/")
            && !returnUrl.StartsWith("//") && !returnUrl.StartsWith("/\\"))
        {
            return this.Redirect(returnUrl);
        }

        return this.RedirectToAction("Index", "Home");
    }

    this.ModelState.AddModelError(string.Empty, "The user name or password provided is incorrect.");

    return this.View(model);
}

public ActionResult LogOff()
{
    FormsAuthentication.SignOut();

    return this.RedirectToAction("Index", "Home");
}
```

Comment: i was hoping to use System.Web.Security as much as possible. through that i was able to retrieve AccountLocked. now i need to know how to instantiate my LDAP Activedirectory as an object so that i can get its object properties. anyone know how it can be achieved?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I manage to do it using a combination of System.Web.Security and System.DirectoryServices.

```
public bool IsExpired(MembershipUser user, LoginModel model)
{
    bool result = false;

    string ldap = ConfigurationManager.ConnectionStrings["ADConnectionString"].ConnectionString;

    DirectoryEntry rootEntry = new DirectoryEntry(ldap, model.UserName, model.Password, AuthenticationTypes.Secure);

    DirectorySearcher mySearcher = new DirectorySearcher(rootEntry);

    SearchResultCollection results;
    string filter = "maxPwdAge=*";
    mySearcher.Filter = filter;

    results = mySearcher.FindAll();
    long maxDays = 0;
    if (results.Count >= 1)
    {
        Int64 maxPwdAge = (Int64)results[0].Properties["maxPwdAge"][0];
        maxDays = maxPwdAge / -864000000000;
    }

    long daysLeft = 0;

    daysLeft = maxDays - DateTime.Today.Subtract(user.LastPasswordChangedDate).Days;

    if (daysLeft <0)
    {
        result = true;
    } else
    {
        if (daysLeft<=14)
        {
            this.Expiring = true;
            this.ExpiringString = String.Format("You must change your password within" + " {0} days", daysLeft);
        }       
        else
        {
            this.Expiring = false;
        }     
    }

    return result;
}
```

Answer (score 2):

The easiest way is to PInvoke LogonUser Win32 API.e.g
 http://www.pinvoke.net/default.aspx/advapi32/LogonUser.html

Read also MSDN reference: https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa378184.aspx

The examples for your questions: https://www.codeproject.com/articles/18102/howto-almost-everything-in-active-directory-via-c

Comment: i was hoping to use System.Web.Security as much as possible. through that i was able to retrieve AccountLocked. now i need to know how to instantiate my LDAP Activedirectory as an object so that i can get its object properties. anyone know how it can be achieved?

Comment: I've changed my answer and added link for example.

Comment: hey thank you for your help. i managed to solve it using another method. i have uploaded the answer. you may take a look.

Comment: I'm glad you found the answer.

Answer (score 2):

I got here from Google search and I found the current answers to be outdated and/or cumbersome (I don't want to import COM dlls, and I would like to avoid complex arithmetics if possible). In addition, it seems that the accepted answer doesn't take into account more granular settings for `maxPwdAge` that could be in effect.

I found out that AD exposes the calculated property [`msDS-UserPasswordExpiryTimeComputed`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/openspecs/windows_protocols/ms-adts/f9e9b7e2-c7ac-4db6-ba38-71d9696981e9) which can be used directly, instead of performing complex calculations:

```
public DateTime? GetPasswordExpirationTime()
{
  var path = @"LDAP://yourserver";
  // null uses the current user's credentials.
  var user = "yourUserNameOrNull";
  var password = "yourPasswordOrNull";
  var idToSearch = "userNameToCheck";
  using(var entry = new DirectoryEntry(path, user, password, AuthenticationTypes.Secure))
  using(var ds = GetSearcher(entry, $"(sAMAccountName={idToSearch})"))
  {
    ds.PropertiesToLoad.Add("msDS-UserPasswordExpiryTimeComputed");
    var user = ds.FindOne();
    return DateTimePropertyFromLong(user, "msDS-UserPasswordExpiryTimeComputed")
  }
}

public static DateTime? DateTimePropertyFromLong(SearchResult sr, string propName)
{
  if (!sr.Properties.Contains(propName)) return null;
  var value = (long) sr.Properties[propName][0];
  return value == long.MaxValue ? (DateTime?)null : DateTime.FromFileTimeUtc(value);
}
```

The relevant bits are just `PropertiesToLoad.Add("msDS-UserPasswordExpiryTimeComputed")` and the conversion from the strange long format returned by AD via the `DateTime.FromFileTimeUtc` method.

**Edit**
As per @t3chb0t, GetSearcher is a simple helper method, responsible for opening a `DirectorySearcher` over the `DirectoryEntry`:

```cs
private static DirectorySearcher GetSearcher(DirectoryEntry entry, string filter = null)
{
    if (filter == null)
        return new DirectorySearcher(entry) {ClientTimeout = TimeSpan.FromSeconds(30)};
    return new DirectorySearcher(entry, filter) {ClientTimeout = TimeSpan.FromSeconds(30)};
}
```

Comment: What is `GetSearcher` and when does it come from?

Comment: @t3chb0t edited the answer to include the helper method body.

Comment: Works! One hint for others: I had to write `LDAP` in upper-case as lower-case wouldn't bind.

Answer (score 1):

Here's another approach to getting the user's account password expiration date, and from the result you can easily calculate IsExpired:

```
public static DateTime GetPasswordExpirationDate(UserPrincipal user)
{
    DirectoryEntry deUser = (DirectoryEntry)user.GetUnderlyingObject();
    ActiveDs.IADsUser nativeDeUser = (ActiveDs.IADsUser)deUser.NativeObject;
    return nativeDeUser.PasswordExpirationDate;
}
```

You'll need to add a reference to the ActiveDS COM library typically found at C:\Windows\System32\activeds.tlb.